# How to create a new instance with existing deployments in google cloud

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, bitnami

I am new to the GCP. I am into a situation that I launched a service for Elasticsearch from the Marketplace which is 'Elasticsearch Certified by Bitnami'. An instance was created for that, but I was unable to access it via HTTP despite that I allowed Http and Https from Firewall. So, I thought to delete that instance and create a new instance that maybe I messed up something. As I go to the marketplace again for the same service as mentioned above. There was an option for 'View Past Deployments' on that there is still the deployment for which I already deleted the instance. I am not sure what can I do about that now. Can anyone please guide me? Can I use the same deployment by creating a new instance? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Delete the deployment and not the VM instance.

Comment: I already deleted the instance. But the deployment is still there! Isn't there anything that I could keep that deployment but use with a new instance? Or I have to delete the deployment as well and start from the beginning?

Comment: Delete the deployment and start over.